# posterior probability thats zero

Tags: probability

I have a problem that given previous discrete data 3, 0, 2, compute the predicted probabilites of next data is 0, 3 or higher than 3.

I have computed the posterior probability that's confirmed correct. However, due to it being a gamma distribution, it takes a form of\begin{equation} C*\lambda^ae^{-b\lambda}, \end{equation} which results in a probability of zero for the next value to be zero which seems really strange given the data 3, 0, 2. 
Please help!

Comment: Why do you say these are from "a gamma distribution"?  As you say, that seems very odd, given that $0$ is one of the observed values.  If you have more information, please add it to the problem statement.

Comment: that's given in the problem statement that the prior is gamma distributed as Gamma(4,5)